# Retrieve specific year in the format of "2019-05-04 11:20:22.697" in SQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql, date

How can I retrieve specific year in the format of “2019-05-04 11:20:22.697” in SQL query? I need the date between 2019 and 2020.

```
select * from date where date between '2019-01-01' and '2020-01-01'
```

Comment: Your title and body text do not agree.  Regarding the actual question, do you want to include the full day of Jan 1st 2020?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Oh sorry,i just need the 2019,it gonna be '2019-01-01' and '2019-12-31' but it will not working for the format which contains the HH MM SS....for this one,,how can i do ?

Comment: What datatype is the column `date`? Please don't say it's a string, and that you're actually using a native timestamp datatype?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a query to just target the year 2019, then use:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE date >= '2019-01-01' AND date < '2020-01-01';
```

This will include the entire 2019 calendar year, up to, but not including, January 1 of 2020.  Note also that the above `WHERE` clause, as written, is *sargable*, meaning that the above query could take advantage of an index on the `date` column for doing the search.